# Is there any way to determine how many characters will be written by sprintf?

Tags: c++, string, printf

I'm working in C++.

I want to write a potentially very long formatted string using sprintf (specifically a secure counted version like _snprintf_s, but the idea is the same).  The approximate length is unknown at compile time so I'll have to use some dynamically allocated memory rather than relying on a big static buffer.  Is there any way to determine how many characters will be needed for a particular sprintf call so I can always be sure I've got a big enough buffer?

My fallback is I'll just take the length of the format string, double it, and try that.  If it works, great, if it doesn't I'll just double the size of the buffer and try again.  Repeat until it fits.  Not exactly the cleverest solution.

It looks like C99 supports passing NULL to snprintf to get the length.  I suppose I could create a module to wrap that functionality if nothing else, but I'm not crazy about that idea.

Maybe an fprintf to "/dev/null"/"nul" might work instead?  Any other ideas?

EDIT: Alternatively, is there any way to "chunk" the sprintf so it picks up mid-write?  If that's possible it could fill the buffer, process it, then start refilling from where it left off.

Answer (score 26):

The man page for `snprintf` says:

```
   Return value
       Upon  successful  return,  these  functions return the number of
       characters printed (not including the trailing '\0' used to  end
       output to strings).  The functions snprintf and vsnprintf do not
       write more than size bytes (including the  trailing  '\0').   If
       the output was truncated due to this limit then the return value
       is the number of characters (not including  the  trailing  '\0')
       which  would  have  been  written  to the final string if enough
       space had been available. Thus, a return value of size  or  more
       means  that  the  output  was  truncated.  (See also below under
       NOTES.)  If an output error is encountered, a negative value  is
       returned.
```

What this means is that you can call `snprintf` with a size of 0.  Nothing will get written, and the return value will tell you how much space you need to allocate to your string:

```
int how_much_space = snprintf(NULL, 0, fmt_string, param0, param1, ...);
```

Comment: It's still a better idea to try and output to a fixed-size stack variable first since the vast majority of printf's will be below a certain size. That means the vast majority don't need the print/malloc/print/free but just print. Only the small number over the limit need the full behavior.

Comment: @Pax: probably true, but that's a performance optimisation. It's often appropriate but not always. An example of when it isn't: you don't have much stack space, and you expect the vast majority of prints to be bigger than any buffer size you're happy putting on the stack. So you always use the heap.

Comment: Given this scenario, why not pre-allocate a _dedicated_ portion of memory for the prints in the heap and benefit from the performance optimisation?

Comment: How does sprintf calculate the actual number of bytes needed?

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, `snprintf()` will return the number of characters required in a buffer to prevent the output from being truncated.  You can simply call it with a 0 buffer length parameter to get the required size then use an appropriately sized buffer.

For a slight improvement in efficiency, you can call it with a buffer that's large enough for the normal case and only do a second call to `snprintf()` if the output is truncated. In order to make sure the buffer(s) are properly freed in that case, I'll often use an `auto_buffer<>` object that handles the dynamic memory for me (and has the default buffer on the stack to avoid a heap allocation in the normal case).

If you're using a Microsoft compiler, MS has a non-standard `_snprintf()` that has serious limitations of not always null terminating the buffer and not indicating how big the buffer should be.

To work around Microsoft's non-support, I use [a nearly public domain `snprintf()` from Holger Weiss](http://www.jhweiss.de/software/snprintf.html).

Of course if your non-MS C or C++ compiler is missing `snprintf()`, the code from the above link should work just as well.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a two-stage approach. Generally, a large percentage of output strings will be under a certain threshold and only a few will be larger.

Stage 1, use a reasonable sized static buffer such as 4K. Since `snprintf()` can restrict how many characters are written, you won't get a buffer overflow. What you *will* get returned from `snprintf()` is the number of characters it *would* have written if your buffer had been big enough.

If your call to `snprintf()` returns less than 4K, then use the buffer and exit. As stated, the vast majority of calls should just do that.

Some will not and that's when you enter stage 2. If the call to `snprintf()` won't fit in the 4K buffer, you at least now know how big a buffer you need.

Allocate, with `malloc()`, a buffer big enough to hold it then `snprintf()` it again to that new buffer. When you're done with the buffer, free it.

We worked on a system in the days before `snprintf()` and we acheived the same result by having a file handle connected to `/dev/null` and using `fprintf()` with that. /dev/null was always guaranteed to take as much data as you give it so we would actually get the size from that, then allocate a buffer if necessary.

Keep in kind that not all systems have `snprintf()` (for example, I understand it's `_snprintf()` in Microsoft C) so you may have to find the function that does the same job, or revert to the `fprintf /dev/null` solution.

Also be careful if the data can be changed between the size-checking `snprintf()` and the actual `snprintf()` to the buffer (i.e., wathch out for threads). If the sizes increase, you'll get buffer overflow corruption.

If you follow the rule that data, once handed to a function, belongs to that function *exclusively* until handed back, this won't be a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, the snprintf() function is not standard C++.  I just tried to use it with Visual Studio 2008 Express Edition, and the compiler reports snprintf not found.

Comment: i think it's _snprintf() in microsoft c++

Comment: @rubancache, that's when you use the "fprintf to /dev/null" solution.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, `asprintf` is a GNU extension that manages this functionality. It accepts a pointer as an output argument, along with a format string and a variable number of arguments, and writes back to the pointer the address of a properly-allocated buffer containing the result.

You can use it like so:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char *hi = "hello"; // these could be really long
    char *everyone = "world";
    char *message;
    asprintf(&message, "%s %s", hi, everyone);
    puts(message);
    free(message);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

I've looked for the same functionality you're talking about, but as far as I know, something as simple as the C99 method is not available in C++, because C++ does not currently incorporate the features added in C99 (such as snprintf).

Your best bet is probably to use a stringstream object.  It's a bit more cumbersome than a clearly written sprintf call, but it will work.

Comment: I didn't do it but I can see maybe why it was done. You don't need C99 since there are PD versions of snprintf() out there. Or maybe because question specifically asked for a printf() solution rather than stringstream. I dunno, I've long since given up trying to understand drive-by downvoters.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CodeProject: CString-clone Using Standard C++](http://69.10.233.10/KB/string/stdstring.aspx?display=Print). It uses solution you suggested with enlarging buffer size.

`// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // FUNCTION:  FormatV
    //      void FormatV(PCSTR szFormat, va_list, argList);
    //

    // DESCRIPTION:
    //      This function formats the string with sprintf style format-specs. 
    //      It makes a general guess at required buffer size and then tries
    //      successively larger buffers until it finds one big enough or a
    //      threshold (MAX_FMT_TRIES) is exceeded.
    //
    // PARAMETERS: 
    //      szFormat - a PCSTR holding the format of the output
    //      argList - a Microsoft specific va_list for variable argument lists
    //
    // RETURN VALUE: 
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------`

```
void FormatV(const CT* szFormat, va_list argList)
{
#ifdef SS_ANSI

    int nLen    = sslen(szFormat) + STD_BUF_SIZE;
    ssvsprintf(GetBuffer(nLen), nLen-1, szFormat, argList);
    ReleaseBuffer();
#else
    CT* pBuf            = NULL;
    int nChars          = 1;
    int nUsed           = 0;
    size_type nActual   = 0;
    int nTry            = 0;

    do  
    {
        // Grow more than linearly (e.g. 512, 1536, 3072, etc)

        nChars          += ((nTry+1) * FMT_BLOCK_SIZE);
        pBuf            = reinterpret_cast<CT*>(_alloca(sizeof(CT)*nChars));
        nUsed           = ssnprintf(pBuf, nChars-1, szFormat, argList);

        // Ensure proper NULL termination.
        nActual         = nUsed == -1 ? nChars-1 : SSMIN(nUsed, nChars-1);
        pBuf[nActual+1]= '\0';


    } while ( nUsed < 0 && nTry++ < MAX_FMT_TRIES );

    // assign whatever we managed to format

    this->assign(pBuf, nActual);
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using C++, there's really no need to use any version of sprintf. The simplest thing to do is use a std::ostringstream.

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << a << " " << b << std::endl;
```

`oss.str()` returns a std::string with the contents of what you've written to oss. Use `oss.str().c_str()` to get a `const char *`. It's going to be a lot easier to deal with in the long run and eliminates memory leaks or buffer overruns. Generally, if you're worrying about memory issues like that in C++, you're not using the language to its full potential, and you should rethink your design.

Comment: A word of warning: C++ has packed a lot of little extras into the streaming functions, and these can bite you in a major way. In particular, the streams support locales, which can change the way your numbers are formatted. Numbers which were output in a stream set to one locale cannot be read into a stream using a different locale.

If you can guarantee that no other locales will ever be used, then you are fine. We got bitten by this because we were using a DLL that plugged into a host application that uses locales.